# Regex.Matches returns one match per line, not per "word"

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm having a hard time understanding why the following expression `\\[B.+\\]` and code returns a Matches count of 1:

```
string r = "\\[B.+\\]";
return Regex.Matches(Markup, sRegEx);
```

I want to find all the instances (let's call them 'tags') (in a variable length HTML string **Markup** that contains no line breaks) that are prefixed by **B** and are enclosed in square brackets.

If the markup contains `[BName]`, I get one match - **good.**

If the markup contains `[BName] [BAddress]`, I get one match - **why?**

If the markup contains `[BName][BAddress]`, I also only get one match.

On some web-based regex testers, I've noticed that if the text contains a CR character, I'll get a match per line - but I need some way to specify that I want matches returned independent of line breaks.

I've also poked around in the Groups and Captures collections of the MatchCollection, but to no avail - always just one result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting only one match because, by default, .NET regular expressions are "greedy"; they try to match as much as possible with a single match.

So if your value is `[BName][BAddress]` you will have one match - which will match the entire string; so it will match from the `[B` at the beginning all the way to the *last* `]` - instead of the first one. If you want two matches, use this pattern instead: `\\[B.+?\\]`

The `?` after the `+` tells the matching engine to match as little as possible... leaving the second group to be its own match.

Slaks also noted an excellent option; specifying specifically that you *do not* wish to match the ending `]` as part of the content, like so: `\\[B[^\\]]+\\]` That keeps your match 'greedy', which might be useful in some other case. In this specific instance, there may not be much difference - but it's an important thing to keep in mind depending on what data/patterns you might be dealing with specifically.

---

On a side note, I recommend using the C# "literal string" specifier `@` for regular expression patterns, so that you do not need to double-escape things in regex patterns; So I would set the pattern like so:

```
string pattern = @"\[B.+?\]";
```

This makes it much easier to figure out regular expressions that are more complex

Comment: Awesome - prompt, well-written and even included some extra tips!  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try the regex string `\\[B.+?\\]` instead.  `.+` on it's own (same is pretty much true for `.*`) will match against as many characters as possible, whereas `.+?` (or `.*?`) will match against the bare minimum number of characters whilst still satisfying the rest of the expression.

Comment: +1 for also mentioning that the `?` quantifier modifier can also be used against `*` when used as a quantifier. Believe it or not, it can also be used against `?`. Just note that with `*` and `?`, it will try to match 0 times, if possible. Sometimes that can cause seemingly odd results.

Answer (score 1):

`.+` is a greedy match; it will match as much as possible.
In your second example, it matches `BName] [BAddress`.

You should write `\[B[^\]]+\]`.
`[^\]]` matches every character except `]`, so it is forced to stop before the first `]`.

Comment: +1 ; this could very well be a better option than the single one I initially posted, depending on the data in question. It might not make a difference in *this* case, but it's probably better in the general case of matching something that looks like a 'tag'. I added this (with attribution) to my answer.